# Como fazer verificação de senhas criptografadas com as senhas do input do usuário no banco de dados?

Tags: java, html, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um programa em que o usuário irá colocar o login e a senha antes de entrar no sistema,e depois de ele colocar o input dele,as senhas irão ser salvas no banco de dados,e depois eu irei verificar se as senhas criptografadas batem com os inputs do usuário.

Exemplo :

O usuário digitou :

```
username : 123456

password : 123456
```

E depois disto,a criptografia de hash vai transformá-los em :

```
username : E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E

password : E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E
```

Após isto será salva no banco de dados,mas lá eu quero verificar quando o usuário digitar de novo a mesma senha,verificar se é igual e bate com o hash gerado.

Estou fazendo este programa que gera o hash em Java e será utilizado no html,para depois ser salvo no banco de dados.

**Como posso fazer isto ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu uso o seguinte.
Gravo a senha do usuário em forma de hash e quando vou validar essa senha eu gero o hash no input do usuário e comparo esse hash do input com o que esta armazenado no banco de dados

Validação usando uma funcao, Fiz o exemplo no Oracle.
a função recebe a senha e login(que com certeza será unico na sua tabela)
voce passa a senha ja aplicado o hash para a funcao e ela retorno 0 para falso e 1 para true. Aqui eu comparo as senhas criptografadas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_VALIDAR_ACESSO(P_SENHAASH IN VARCHAR2, P_LOGIN IN VARCHAR2) RETURN  NUMBER IS
V_RETORNO NUMBER(1);
V_CONTADOR NUMBER(2);
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_CONTADOR 
FROM PCEMPR 
WHERE USUARIOBD = P_LOGIN 
AND SENHABD = P_SENHAASH;

IF V_CONTADOR = 0 THEN
V_RETORNO := 0;-- 0 PARA FALSE
ELSE
V_RETORNO := 1;-- 1 PRA TRUE
END IF;



RETURN V_RETORNO;
END;
```

Seu Codigo :

```
Create procedure funcaoValidar
@username
@password
as 
begin
declare @existe int
set @existe = (select count(*) 
              from armazenarSenhas 
              where username = @username /*usar operador AND, virgula nao funciona..*/
              and password = @password)
if @existe > 0
print 'Login válido'
else
print 'Não há nenhum login válido'
end
```

Comment: Mas esse input que você compara você faz manualmente ou faz pelo banco de dados ?

Comment: No sistema que eu fiz, quem gera o hash e minha aplicação, então eu gero pra gravar e gero pra comparar com o que esá gravado, voce está gerando esse hash pelo BD ?

Comment: Pra compaar pelo Banco de dados, você pode criar uma função de validar login que recebe os o input que o usuário digitou já com o hash aplicado e comparar com o que está gravado

Comment: Então,estou usando o Java para gerar o hash e depois eu estou gravando o hash no BD,agora estou querendo saber como fazer a verificação,vou tentar fazer aqui do jeito que você falou.Mas logo que o usuário digita o input já é gerado o hash,então não tem como eu comparar.

Comment: Se nao conseguir eu tento montar um exemplo aqui pra ver se te da uma ideia

Comment: Tentei assim,já que o input do usuário já estava sendo gerado logo após ele colocar as informações,eu criei duas variáveis que iriam pegar o input do usuário antes de ser transformado em hash e salvei elas também no banco e depois comparei a senha sem ser gerada o hash com a senha gerada com o hash. Será que deste jeito funciona ?

Comment: mais se voce comparar a senha sem hash com a senha com o hash sempre vai dar falso. Vou fazer um exemplo aqui ai vc ver se e isso que vc quer...

Comment: Ok,agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Olá amigo,obrigado por tentar ajudar,mas estou fazendo mesmo no MySQL e este código achei que não irá ajudar muito.

Comment: ok, mas tente ver se a lógica te ajuda... e aplica no banco que vc estiver usando.

Comment: Você compara a senha salva no banco de dados já com hash com o input do usuário ? Pois eu fiz algo parecido mas não sei se vai funcionar.

Comment: Isso, nesse exemplo ai e exatamente isso.

Comment: Criei uma procedure e postei,será que esta iria funcionar ou não ?

Comment: Aparentemente sim, porém acho que tem que ter um `count`  no seu select

Comment: Pronto,já alterei o código.

Comment: Eu nao tenho base MySql aqui pra testar seu codigo, fiz algumas correcoes ali e postei, executa e verifica se dará certo...

Comment: Olá amigo,vou testar aqui esta procedure modificada que você mostrou,mas parece funcionar,então já dei +1 e também como uma resposta que me ajudou.

Answer (score 2):

Desde que seu algoritmo de geração do hash gere os mesmo valores quando aplicado sobre os mesmo parâmetros, você pode comparar o input do usuário criptografado com o valor criptografado do banco.

Então segundo o seu exemplo quando o usuário 123456 informar seus dados na tela de login você deve fazer a comparação:

```
if ((meuGeradorDeHash(nomeUsuarioInformado) = nomeJaCriptografadoNoBanco) &&
    (meuGeradorDeHash(senhaUsuarioInformada) = senhaJaCriptografadaNoBanco)) {
    // login válido
}
```

Comment: Também posso fazer com este seu exemplo algo parecido no banco de dados,não ? Pois pelo Java eu estou somente utilizando para criptografar com o MD5.

Comment: Sim, dependendo do banco de dados já tem função nativa pra gerar MD5 também.

Comment: Então,estou criando uma tabela que vai armazenar os valores do username e password,e estou querendo criar um procedure que vai fazer esta verificação que você colocou como exemplo,mas estou sem ideia de como fazer isto.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as respostas, se o seu projeto não for especificamente o algoritmo de gerar o hash, é melhor deixar essa função para bibliotecas especializadas, vide [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html).

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
...
String digest = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(data);
```

Comment: Olá amigo,meu projeto é especificamente somente para gerar o hash e depois passar as variáveis para o banco de dados para comparação entre  o hash gerado e  o input do usuário.

Comment: Então é isso que o Emerson falou mesmo, tendo o método para gerar o hash, você tem que comparar gerando o hash novamente com o que está armazenado no banco, você não deve tentar desfazer o hash, se é que me entende.

Comment: Sim eu entendo,até por que com o MD5 não é possível desfazer a criptografia,vou tentar aqui o que foi explicado nas respostas.